# C - mktime altering passed time_t value

Tags: c

I need the functionality for a user to enter a timestamp, store that timestamp on the disk, then display that timestamp at a later time. I also need to be able to determine the distance between two timestamps.

My current solution is to use the time.h utility as follows:

To read a given timestamp of the form "MO/DA/YEAR HR:MI"

```c
time_t readable_to_epoch(char* str) {
    int mo, da, yr, hr, mi;
    sscanf(str, "%d/%d/%d %d:%d", &mo, &da, &yr, &hr, &mi);
    
    struct tm timeinfo;
    time_t out;
    timeinfo.tm_mon = mo - 1;
    timeinfo.tm_mday = da;
    timeinfo.tm_year = yr - 1900;
    timeinfo.tm_hour = hr;
    timeinfo.tm_min = mi;
    timeinfo.tm_sec = 0;

    out = mktime(&timeinfo);
    return out;
}
```

To convert a given time_t into a human readable form:

```c
// WARNING returned string must be freed;
char* epoch_to_readable(time_t time) {
    return asctime(localtime(&time));
}
```

My issue is that if I pass in the input:
06/19/2018 12:52
The conversion to time_t and back is as desired. Here is the test harness output:

```
original: 06/19/2018 12:52
epoch time: 1529437920
converted readable: Tue Jun 19 12:52:00 2018
```

But when I pass in the input:
01/01/2022 10:00
The converted readable seems to be one hour behind:

```
original: 01/01/2022 10:00
epoch time: 1641056400
converted readable: Sat Jan  1 09:00:00 2022
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and google isn't helping. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: firstly you should classify the problem is converting from original readable  -> epoch or epoch -> converted readable. I suggest you use this https://www.epochconverter.com/ as reference value, hope it can help you.

Comment: 1) You did not say which conversion you think is wrong. 2) You're talking about localtime, but did not provide your time zone

Comment: Re "*WARNING returned string must be freed*", Quite the opposite. It must NOT be freed.

Comment: Thank you for the comments :) I will remove the WARNING. @ikegmai I'm fairly sure the first conversion (readable -> epoch) is wrong, as the time incorrectly displays in epochconverter.com

Comment: Time zones cause endless confusion.  The library you have may be misapplying time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set `timeinfo.tm_isdst`, so you're getting undefined behaviour. You should use `-1`.

> Daylight Saving Time flag. The value is positive if DST is in effect, zero if not and negative if no information is available

Note that working with local times without offset is inherently buggy. Because of Daylight Saving Time, time stamps from two hours each year are indistinguishable from each other.

Comment: Thanks so much! I added the change, but now the second case works and the first one doesn't. 06/19/2018 12:52 now evaluates to 1529441520. In epochconverter.com it is showing this value to be one hour BELOW the desired time ( Tuesday, June 19, 2018 1:52:00 PM GMT-07:00 DST ), and in the test harness it is shown to be one hour ABOVE the desired time (Tue Jun 19 13:52:00 2018). Could leaving tm_yday and tm_wday undefined be contributing?

Comment: I just added tm_yday = -1, tm_wday = -1 and it still doesn't work. I also tried tm_yday = 0 and tm_wday = 0 and still nothing. Would you have suggestions from here?

Comment: FYI, the manpage for mktime has the following paragraph: `The mktime() function modifies the fields of the tm structure as follows: tm_wday and tm_yday are set to values determined from the  contents  of  the  other  fields; if structure members are outside their valid interval, they will be normalized (so that, for example, 40 October is changed into 9 November); tm_isdst is set (regardless of its initial value) to a positive value or to 0, respectively, to indicate whether  DST  is  or is not in effect at the specified time.`

Comment: You still haven't provided your time zone